# Set/Get Extras in Multiple Instances of Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have an Android Notification who sent an Id to the destination Activity. 
To do that, I use a Intent with putExtra like This:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this.context, ConfirmationActivity.class);

resultIntent.putExtra("Id", idToSent);

resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The problem it is when I call the Notification 2, 3 or more time. When I use the "getExtras" in the method onCreate of the Activity, it always have the same Id (The last Id sent by the last notification instance)

I had try changing the Intent's Flags, but I can't find the right combination

Can someone help me with this?

How I do to have, lets say, 3 instances of a notification and when i click on the notification, sent 3 diferents Id to the Activity?

This is my full code:

//Notification Manager Class

```
public void sendNearPromotionNotification(int idToSent){

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context);

    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Title));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text));
    notificationBuilder.setTicker(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Ticket));
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    int apiLevel = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = null;   

    if (apiLevel < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){     

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this.context, ConfirmationActivity.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra("Id", idToSent);

        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }else{

        Intent addWishListIntent = new Intent(this.context,  IntentServiceNotifications.class);

        addWishListIntent.putExtra("Id", idToSent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this.context, 0, addWishListIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon2, "Add a WishList", pendingIntent);
    }

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(idToSent, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

//ConfirmationActivity Class

```
public class PromotionConfirmationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_transparent);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null)
            id = extras.getInt("Id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    private static class IDGenerator {

         private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

         public static int nextValue() {
             return counter.getAndIncrement();
         }
    }


    ...

    resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, IDGenerator.nextValue(), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

The documentation claims that the id sent as second parameter is not used, but in fact it is needed for these kind of purposes.